# Dreamweaver muestra errores is defined but never used, is not defined, use strict en código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

Tengo un JS para para un tooltip que funciona pero en dreamweaver me muestra los varios errores

> 'mostrarTooltip' is defined but never used
>   Missing "use strict" statement
>   'X' is not defined
>   [image]

La pregunta es porque estos errores y cómo corregirlos

```js
/*
*
* Autor: Ivan Salas Corrales
* blog: http://programando-o-intentandolo.blogspot.com.es/
*
*/

function mostrarTooltip(elemento,mensaje){

    // Si no existe aun el tooltip se crea
    if (!document.getElementById(elemento.id+"tp") ){

        // Dimensiones del elemento al que se quiere añadir el tooltip
        anchoElemento = $('#'+elemento.id).width();
        altoElemento = $('#'+elemento.id).height();
        
        // Coordenadas del elemento al que se quiere añadir el tooltip
        coordenadaXElemento = $('#'+elemento.id).position().left;
        coordenadaYElemento = $('#'+elemento.id).position().top;

        // Coordenadas en las que se colocara el tooltip
        x = coordenadaXElemento + anchoElemento/2 + 20;
        y = coordenadaYElemento + altoElemento/2 + 10;

        // Crea el tooltip con sus atributos
        var tooltip = document.createElement('div');
        tooltip.id = elemento.id + "tp";
        tooltip.className = 'toolTip';
        tooltip.innerHTML = mensaje;
        tooltip.style.left = x + "px";
        tooltip.style.top = y + "px";

        // Añade el tooltip
        document.body.appendChild(tooltip); 
    }

    // Cambia la opacidad del tooltip y lo muestra o lo oculta (Si el raton esta encima del elemento se muestra el tooltip y sino se oculta)
    $('#'+elemento.id).hover(
        function(){
            tooltip.style.display = "block";
            $('#'+tooltip.id).animate({"opacity" : 1});

        },
        function(){
            $('#'+tooltip.id).animate({"opacity" : 0});
            setTimeout(
                function (){
                    tooltip.style.display = "none";
                }, 
                400
            );
            
        }
    );    
}
```

```css
.toolTip {
 background: rgba(20,20,20,0.9) url('../img/info.gif') center left 5px no-repeat;
 border: 2px solid #87cefa;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #333;
 color: #87cefa;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
 max-width: 600px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100; 
}

.toolTip {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Nunc et vulputate neque. Proin tincidunt, elit sed volutpat ornare, tortor nunc porta ipsum, ac pharetra metus magna ac dui. Fusce eu felis risus. Aliquam accumsan venenatis egestas. Morbi vel eros egestas lectus fringilla aliquet at sit amet odio. Aliquam sed sapien justo, non auctor turpis. Donec leo massa, accumsan eget iaculis ut, <span id="palabra1" onmouseover="mostrarTooltip(this,'<p> Praesent dui leo, sagittis at adipiscing eget, ornare sed lectus. </p>');">facilisis</span>


   <p> Duis tincidunt, elit non malesuada ornare, sapien tortor <span id="palabra2" onmouseover="mostrarTooltip(this,'Esta es una palabra');"/>fringilla</span> magna
```

Comment: Es un inspector de estilo. Si tu código funciona, podrías desactivarlo. Si quieres seguir usándolo y desaparecer los mensajes, solo tienes que hacerles caso: 1. Si te falta, agrégalo. 2. Si no lo has definido, defínelo. 3. Si lo defines, úsalo.

Comment: @Rubén ya subi el html, en mi pc funciona normalmente de hecho lo tengo funcionado asi. pero me genera la duda porque me muestra esos errores y como los soluciono.

Comment: @toledano tolenado disculpa el arevimiento es que no se como definirlo. esos errores son cruciales?

Comment: Pues no son cruciales, pero es una buena práctica de programación tenerlos en cuenta. Como no son errores, no se corrigen. Son mejoras... en inglés se dice _linting_, que literalmente significa _quitar la pelusa_. Busca en Google ESLint o JSHint, que siguen reglas de estilo predefinidas.

Comment: @Daniel: Al ejecutar el código, y pasar el puntero del ratón sobre la última palabra, stack-snippet muestra un par de errores. Deben de estar relacionados con lo que te muestra Dreamweaver. A lo mencionado por toledano, cabe agregar que las reglas predefinidas de *linting* asumen que sigues las prácticas "recomendadas" por Dreamweaver. Revisa la documentación de Linting de Dreamweaver.

Comment: algún alma caritativa podría corregir esos errores. Es que no manejo Javascript.

Comment: Agrega `'use strict` al principio de tu archivo. Agrega `var ` (incluido el espacio en blanco) antes de la primera aparición de `anchoElemento`, `x`, `y`, etc., (queda así `var anchoElemento`). __DEBES ignorar__ el error sobre `mostrarTooltip` porque si lo estás usando.

Comment: @toledano muchísimas gracias por el gesto. Solucionado.